# PHP - Show different html if variable is zero or not

Tags: php, mysql

Been searching around here but where only able to find to show/hide if the variable isset or not.

I want to show two different infos depending if the variable is zero or not.
If variable is zero the text input and submit button should be visible.
If variable is not zero the facebook variable should be echoed and the reset button showed.

What am i doing wrong?
Heres my code ive been trying:

```
<?php
$sql2 = $db->query( "SELECT facebook FROM ".$db->prefix."users WHERE id = ".$id);
                while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $sql2 ) ) {

if (empty($row)) {
?>
<input type="hidden" name="form_sent" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="form[facebook]" value="<?php echo pun_htmlspecialchars($user['facebook']) ?>" size="40" maxlength="50" />
<input type="submit" name="update" value="<?php echo $lang_common['Submit'] ?>" />
<?php
} else {
?>
<?php echo pun_htmlspecialchars($user['facebook']) ?>
<a href="reset.php">
<input type="button" value="Request reset" />
</a>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

**FIX** **EDIT**

I just did it this way and it works fine.

```
<?php
if($user['facebook'] == '0'){
echo '<a href="update.php"><input type="button" value="Submit" /></a>';} ?>

<?php
if($user["facebook"] > 0){
echo '<a href="reset.php"><input type="button" value="Request reset" /></a>'; }?>
```

Now why cant i add this in the echo?

```
<input type="text" name="form[facebook]" value="<?php echo 
         pun_htmlspecialchars($user['facebook']) ?>" size="40" 
         maxlength="50" />
```

I guess its because php echoes php?
Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: what does query() return?

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    $sql2 = $db->query( "SELECT facebook FROM ".$db->prefix."users WHERE id = 
    ".$id);

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $sql2 ) ) {

        if ( $row['facebook'] == 0 ) {
            ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="form_sent" value="1" />
            <input type="text" name="form[facebook]" value="<?php echo 
             pun_htmlspecialchars($user['facebook']) ?>" size="40" 
             maxlength="50" />
             <input type="submit" name="update" value="<?php echo 
            $lang_common['Submit'] ?>" />
           <?php

        } else {

           echo pun_htmlspecialchars($user['facebook']) 
           ?>
            <a href="reset.php">
               <input type="button" value="Request reset" />
            </a>
          <?php
        }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when i add this nothing shows.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it this way and it works fine.

```
<?php
if($user['facebook'] == '0'){
echo '<a href="update.php"><input type="button" value="Submit" /></a>';} ?>

<?php
if($user["facebook"] > 0){
echo '<a href="reset.php"><input type="button" value="Request reset" /></a>'; }?>
```

Now why cant i add this in the echo?

```
<input type="text" name="form[facebook]" value="<?php echo 
         pun_htmlspecialchars($user['facebook']) ?>" size="40" 
         maxlength="50" />
```

I guess its because php echoes php?
Is there a workaround for this?